# multi-label time series needed for sorting

Tags: python, sas, time-series, label, dimension

I have a time series data set for imports and exports from IMF.  It has column one as the main country, column two as the counter country, column three as the type (import or export), and the rest of the columns are values, with each column representing a month.  I'm trying to transpose it but it's difficult with the 3 explanation variables (country, counter, and type).  It seems that having a multi-dimensional column/variable label would be great but I haven't found anything making me think it's possible.  Of course I could combine the columns (ie country-counter-type) but this makes it difficult when I need to sort by crisis country.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  This would be great for SAS, Python, R, or Stata.  Thank you.

Edit:

Thanks for the replies.  An example would be something like:

Country     Counter Country                Type            Date        2001-01       2001-02        2001-03

France            US                               Import                            10                   11                  12

France            US                               Export                             4                     5                    6

France            UK                               Import                             1                     2                    3

France            UK                               Export                             2                     3                    4

US                   FR                               IM                                   3                     4                    5

US                   FR                               EX                                  5                     6                    7

US                   UK                               IM                                   4                     5                    6

US                   UK                               EX                                  5                     6                    7

UK                   FR                               IM

UK                   FR                               EX

UK                   US                               IM

UK                   US                               EX

This goes on for over 100 countries with numerous variables, so renaming the labels to something like US_UK_IM isn't ideal.  The idea is that I can sort by country, counter country, or type while also restricting the data to a country (such as the US for the financial crisis, China for the 2015 market event, etc) and mix those events together for my tests.  Ideally I could transpose the data set to make it long with the labels being nested so I could restrict the data to something like both the US being the country and the counter country.

Please let me know if this explanation is helpful or not.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to add more details, including example data and expected output. Make up fake data to include. Please see the guidelines on how to ask a question here [ask]

Comment: I am not sure why you expect that having to use a three variable compound key would be anymore difficult than using a single variable key in any of the languages you mentioned.

Comment: Show what you mean by a "long data set". All the applications indicated can do the work you're describing, as could Excel with a pivot table, though a long table would work much better there. This looks like the standard import export table from governments though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is imported, you can transpose it to a long format using PROC TRANSPOSE. Then filter your data in Excel or SAS using WHERE statements.

Assuming your variables are as shown this would work, you may need to modify it to match your data.

1. Sort your data
2. Transpose to make the dates be rows in your data and a new column with the values
3. Example of filtering
4. (Optional) Export to Excel.

   ```
   proc sort data=have;
   by country counter_country Type;
   run;

   proc transpose data=have out=long;
   by country counter_country type;
   var '2001-01'n -- '2020-12'n; *first and last variables;
   run;

   data long;
   set long;

    month_report = input(compress(_name_, '-'), yymm6.);
   format month_report yymmn6.;

   *then to filter US and counter country is either France/US and for the year 2001;
   data US_France_2001;
    set long;
    where country = 'US' and counter_country in ('France', 'US') and year(month_report) =2001;
   run;
   ```

or Export to Excel:

```
proc export data=long outfile='/folders/myfolders/ImportData.xlsx' dbms=xlsx replace;run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Reeza.  I think you're right, I'm just making it too difficult and my problems transposing it weren't helping me with how I should be looking at it.  Your advice and PGStats on SAS were very helpful.  Thank you.